# Problem with saturated set

Tags: general-topology

In the Wikipedia [Saturated set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_set), the saturation set is defined as follows:

"A set $C$ is said to be **saturated** with respect to a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ if $C$ is a subset of $f$'s domain $X$ and if whenever $f$ sends two points $c\in C$ and $x\in X$ to the same value then $x$ belongs to $C$ (that is, if $f(x)=f(c)$ then $x\in C$)."

I don't understand why x belongs to X initially, but then x belongs to C? It's quite counter-intuitive. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: This means $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$. The condition you are dealing with ensures $\subset$ holds.

Comment: Example: $X=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2.$ Then $C\subset\Bbb R$ is saturated w.r.t. $f$ iff  $\forall c\in C\,(-c\in C).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know that $c \in C$ (hence the choice of symbol) and you have *some* $ x \in X$ (so just in the domain), *then* you're given that in fact $f(x)=f(c)$ and then we can *conclude* that $x \in C$ (which is more specific).

It's showing the inclusion $f[f^{-1}[C]] \subseteq C$ by picking an arbitrary element $x$ on the left hand side and showing it to be in the right hand side.

Comment: Thank you very much!